# Delete file versions on SharePoint via Graph API

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for a Python script that will delete all versions of files on SharePoint via Graph API, except the current one. Does anyone have any experience with this?

I have not found a script to test yet. I expect a script that someone already has in use.